# Setting (intern) variable for color

Tags: colors, powerapps

I'm trying to create a variable so I can use it across my app. I've put the "code" in `OnVisible` in my first screen with the following code:

```
Set(LayoutSettings, {
    colorHR : RGBA(55, 207, 177, 1)
})
```

To test it, I simply used a rectangle and in `Fill` I use have:

```
LayoutSettings.colorHR
```

So basically I have:

```
HomeScreen.OnVisible = Set(LayoutSettings, {colorHR : RGBA(55, 207, 177, 1)})
Rectangle.Fill = LayoutSettings.colorHR
```

But somehow my rectangle is still black. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a single screen in your app? The expressions in the OnVisible property of a screen will only be executed when the screen is shown - either when the app is being opened, or when you navigate from another screen. If that's the case, try adding a new screen, then toggling (in the tree view on the left) between the two screens, and you should get the OnVisible expressions executed.

Comment: @carlosfigueira any idea how i can fix this when using only one screen?

Comment: If you save the app, close it and open it again, then you should have the expressions on the OnVisible property execute.